# nginx upstream server path "backend.example.com/serverfiles/"?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I was wondering how to define server value in upstream to directory path instead of subdomain or port...

for example this won't work :

```
upstream backend  {
  server backend1.example.com/**dir/** ;
  server backend2.example.com:8080;
}
 server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue how could i do this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Nginx won't modify the request parameters, including `get` string.
If you want to modify it before sending to the backend, you should use rewrite.

For example:

```
 server {
  location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$  /somedir/$1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }
```

This will prepend `/somedir/` to every request for that location.
Actual URL in browser won't be modified, just the request sent to the backend.

Comment: Hello @DukeLion,

First, thank you for your reply.

Could you please give me example of that kind of rewrite(remote url) :) ?

Best regards.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example